# If the angular momentum is conserved in a system whose moment of inertia is increased, it's kinetic energy decreases

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, energy-conservation, work

[image: $\Delta$ KE less than zero for increased Moment of Inertia]

The workout that $\Delta K.E.$ is less than zero is attached. But where does this energy go. It is transformed back to rotational KE if moment of inertia decreases. How would you account for the change in Kinetic energy?

Comment: Changing the moment of inertia is only possible by moving some parts of the rigid body, which in turn changes the internal energy of the body.

Comment: Then how would you explain for the increase in Kinetic energy when I is decreased.

Comment: Same, just in one direction the energy increases and the other it decreases. 
Think of yourself on a spinning chair very fast - if you move a bit your hands out, the 'centrifugal force' will pull them out - minimizing energy, and you need to do work to pull them back in - giving y your chair and body more energy

Comment: Liked the use of quotes on 'centrifugal force'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is happening to rotational kinetic energy when moment of inertia is changed?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93508/)

Comment: You have a pretty good pen! But, if you would learn to use Latex/MathJax ([quick tutorial](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9133/32426)) would make it look much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in many comments, the concept of **Work** is integral here.

In Newtonian Mechanics, we have the equation: $$K_{initial} + W = K_{final}$$ Here the work is done by changing the $I$, the moment of inertia. To do this, the mass distribution of the body needs to be shifted further from the axis of rotation.

Naturally, at least some particles of the body need to be moved away from the axis of rotation. To do this an **external force** is required. Displacement of these particle is against the centripetal force causing the rotation - such as tension. This leads to the particle, and hence the system, losing Kinetic Energy. (Negative work is being done by the centripetal force on he particle)

Exactly how much energy is lost is given by the $\Delta E$ you have caculated.

**The above is just an attempt to provide an intuitive view of conservation of angular momentum in view of linear dynamics.**